# Recording Save functionality in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

Suppose If I perform save functionality in recording with one thread count(Blazmeter tool).Now run the same (which I recorded earlier) .jmx file in Jmter with 100 thread count.
My question is whether all 100 data is saved in the Corresponding application database ?
Kindly Guide me

Comment: With appropriate correlation, parameterization and scripting, yes. It will save 100 data points in the application's DB.

Comment: one ID is getteing generated Dynamically when click "Add New" button but that dynamic values are not present in any of the request so i handle with Parameterization concepts still its not yet saved correctly bro.Could you please share your mail id bro

Answer (score 1):

Remember one simple rule: each JMeter thread (virtual user) [must represent a real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) with its own credentials, [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), [headers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/), etc.

Assuming you properly configure JMeter and use different credentials, [handle dynamic request parameter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)s, etc. - you should be able to replay your test with increased amount of threads (virtual users) and they will trigger saving the items to database (you can even check it using [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler)